# Selecting single entry using SearchCursor and creating variable

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I am trying to select a single entry of a floating point entry in a dbf table that contains 9 entries (sampled from a raster image), some of which is NULL using SearchCursor. I want to select one of the entries that is not NULL and assign it as a new variable for use later in my script. I can do a query that excludes NULL values (includes all values greater than 0) but I don't know how to select a single entry that is not NULL and assign as a new variable.

The field name is:

```
Rt_b1
<Null>
0.138817
0.136027
0.136027
<Null>
<Null>
0.136027
0.138817
0.136027
```

I'm using Windows XP and ArcGIS Desktop 10.1

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Sample_TIF2, ("Rt_b1"), '"Rt_b1" > 0') as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
           print str(row[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably want to set your `field name` as a **variable** so that you can reuse it.  Then, build the `query string` outside the cursor function to use the **field name variable**.

Once there, unless I'm missing something in your question, it should be a matter of testing for a `non-null` value in the row.  If this comes up true, retrieve the value and set to a variable.

```
rtfield = "Rt_b1"
querystring = '"' + rtfield + '" > 0'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Sample_TIF2, (rtfield), querystring) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    rtblval = row[0]
```